# How to set IsPublishedTo status on a Tridion Component?

Tags: tridion

After a Tridion CMS Database restore from another environment we cannot unpublish Components from the Broker.  If we publish to the Broker then we can unpublish.  We want to set the IsPublishedTo status to the publish targets available in the new envioronment.

The TOM API has a SetPublishedTo method available for Pages and Component Templates but not Components.

How can I set the PublishedStatus for the Components?  Is it possible using UpdateXML or do we need to perform database black magic?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use the following C# based code in a command line tool for switching the PublishStates of all my items after a SDL Tridion 2009 environment switch (What version are you using?):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS;
using Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDSDefines;
using System.Xml;

namespace SetAllItemsAsUnpublished
{
    /// <summary>
    /// A command line script that can enable/disable users
    /// </summary>
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TDSE tdse = new TDSE();
            User currentUser = tdse.User;
            ListRowFilter listRowFilter = tdse.CreateListRowFilter();
            String xpath = "/tcm:ListPublishItems/*/*[local-name()='Page' or local-name()='Component']";
            listRowFilter.SetCondition("Recursive", true);
            listRowFilter.SetCondition("OnlyPublishedPages", true);
            listRowFilter.SetCondition("OnlyPublishedCPs", true);


            //listRowFilter.SetCondition("ItemType", ItemType.ItemTypePage);

            XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(new NameTable());
            nsmgr.AddNamespace("tcm", "http://www.tridion.com/ContentManager/5.0");

            //Check that the user running the script is an Administrator
            if (currentUser.privileges == TDSPrivileges.TdsPrivilegeSystemAdministrator)
            {
                Publications publications = tdse.GetPublications();
                Console.WriteLine("There are " + publications.Count + " to be processed");
                int i = 0;
                foreach (Publication publication in tdse.GetPublications())
                {
                    ++i;
                    Console.WriteLine(" - Processing " + publication.Title + "(" + i + " of " + publications.Count + ")");
                    foreach( PublicationTarget target in tdse.GetPublicationTargets()){
                        Console.Write("     checking target: " + target.Title);
                        XmlDocument publishedItemsXml = new XmlDocument();
                        try
                        {
                            publishedItemsXml.LoadXml(publication.GetListPublishItems(target.ID, false, false, ListColumnFilter.XMLListID, listRowFilter));
                            foreach (XmlElement publishedItemNode in publishedItemsXml.SelectNodes(xpath, nsmgr))
                            {
                                String uri = publishedItemNode.Attributes["ID"].Value;
                                Console.Write(".");
                                if (publishedItemNode.LocalName == "Page")
                                {
                                    Page page = (Page)tdse.GetObject(uri, EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView, publication, XMLReadFilter.XMLReadAll);
                                    page.SetPublishedTo(target, false, currentUser);
                                    if (page.Info.IsCheckedOut)
                                    {
                                        page.CheckIn(true);
                                    }
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    foreach (XmlElement ctRenderNode in publishedItemNode.SelectNodes("tcm:RenderWith", nsmgr))
                                    {
                                        String uriCT = ctRenderNode.Attributes["ID"].Value;
                                        ComponentTemplate ct = (ComponentTemplate)tdse.GetObject(uriCT, EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView, publication, XMLReadFilter.XMLReadAll);
                                        ct.SetPublishedTo(uri, target, false, currentUser);
                                        if (ct.Info.IsCheckedOut)
                                        {
                                            ct.CheckIn(true);
                                        }
                                    }                                
                                }
                            }
                            Console.WriteLine();
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                //Warn when there is a non-admin user running the script
                Console.WriteLine("You must be an SDL Tridion CMS Administrator to run this application");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Done! Hit ENTER key to close");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So basically setting the CT to UnPublished should do what you need, as the Component is not technically published, it is a Component Presentation based on that CT.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the excellent code sample!  I am using Tridion 2011 and am lucky it is backwards compatible with TOM.  I'll adapt it to set it to published for the targets available in the restored system since we also restore our Broker databases as well and then all is in sync.  Muchos gracias!

Comment: In Tridion 2013 SP1 you can use the new DecommissionPublicationTarget method in the Core Service to set all items as not published..

Answer (score 4):

Components themselves are never published from Tridion, they are only published as part of a Component Presentation (Component + Component Template).

The `SetPublishedTo` method on a Component Template takes a Component as a parameter. So by calling it you can set one Component Presentation as Published or Unpublished.

Once you've unpublished all Component Presentations of a Component, that Component implicitly becomes Unpublished.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - makes sense!  I didn't look at the implementation of Component Template because I was expecting to see Component.  I guess we could have also implemented it on PageTemplate instead of Page.  Maybe historically the Page method was added first then later the ComponentTemplate method.

Comment: I had the same confusion when I first needed to set the published status for my Binary Event Tracker: http://www.sdltridionworld.com/community/2011_extensions/binaryeventtracker.aspx . In that case there really isn't a correct CT, since the extension actually handles implicitly published binaries: the ones where you normally don't use a CT. In the end we let the user configure a CT, which works fine since for implicit binaries the CT is pretty meaningless anyway.