# Cannot unpublish component

Tags: tridion

I am using Tridion R5.3. I am trying to delete a component in but it it showing as published. No matter what I do I cannot get it to unpublish. I ran the following query against the database to determine where the component is published.

```
SELECT *
FROM [dbo].[PUBLISH_STATES] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE REFERENCE_ID = 268494
```

And I received the following information

- ID : 45173
- REFERENCE_ID : 268494
- ITEM_TYPE : 16
- PUBLICATION_ID : 4
- STATE : 1
- STATE_CHANGE_DATE : 2006-08-18 12:50:25.597
- PUBLICATION_TARGET_ID : 2
- TRUSTEE_ID : 43
- TEMPLATE_REFERENCE_ID : 89798
- TEMPLATE_ITEM_TYPE : 32

I have tried to unpublish the component from the publication target with an ID of 2 but no luck.

Would I be safe to just delete the row in the database?

### Update

On the suggestion of Nuno and after reading [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327484/how-to-set-ispublishedto-status-on-a-tridion-component) I figure I have to un-publish the associated component template. I have tried the following and I am getting a `Type Mismatch` when executing the `SetPublishedTo()` method.

```
TDS.TDSE tdse = new TDS.TDSE();
var componentTemplate = (TDS.ComponentTemplate)tdse.GetObject("tcm:4-89798-32", TDSDefines.EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView);
componentTemplate.SetPublishedTo("tcm:4-268494", "tcm:0-2-65537", false, tdse.User);
```

Comment: No you won't, deleting rows in the database is usually what gets you in trouble later down the road. Have you tried changing the published state? (IIRC you can do this with the TOM API, like the old PowerTool used to)

Comment: Accidentally put tridion-2011 as a tag. I'm actually using 5.3. I'll have a go at changing the published state using the TOM API and update.

Comment: In some cases the only solution is to set the STATE to 0. For example if you have removed the publishing target the component is published to.

Comment: The publication target is still there. It's used to publish live content. I have set STATE to 0 and nothing has happened.

Comment: @NunoLinhares I tried setting the published state through the TOM API but got a Type Mismatch exception. Question updated.

Comment: Is your code compiled for x86? I had this issue with TOM Interops all the time when I did 5.3 (that was a LONG TIME ago). You can also try using a different version of .NET instead of v4 (interops changed a bit with version 4, like introduction of optional parameters) or even try generating the interops yourself by adding cm_tom.dll as a reference instead of using the Tridion-provided interops (CAUTION: DON'T EVER DO THIS UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING!!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After contacting SDL Support the solution was to set the `STATE` field to `0` in both the `ITEM_STATES` and `PUBLISH_STATES` tables for the relevant component.

```
UPDATE dbo.ITEM_STATES
SET STATE = 0
WHERE ITEM_REFERENCE_ID = 268494

UPDATE dbo.PUBLISH_STATES
SET STATE = 0
WHERE REFERENCE_ID = 268494
```