# Component will not delete

Tags: tridion

I'm doing a bit tidy of the Content Manager and have a component that won't delete (not the same as [my other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13685283/cannot-unpublish-component)).

When I try to delete the component in question I get the following error

```
(8004032D) This item is in use.
Unable to delete Component (tcm:4-65020).

UtilitiesBL.AssertItemCanBeDeleted
UtilitiesBL.AssertItemCanBeDeleted
ComponentBL.Delete
Component.Delete
Request.Delete
```

When I use the `Where Used` tool on the component I get no results in the "Used In" tab, one result in the "Uses" tab, the "Blueprint Hierachy" shows it is not localized in any of my three child publications and no results in the "Published To" tab.

I have had a look in the Content Manager database to see if I can spot what is going wrong but not really found anything.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: When you say that the component isn't used anywhere, do you mean you checked its Where Used popup? Does it show any items in the "Used By" tab?

Comment: Maybe it's localized? Or used on a page in a child publication? I believe the 'where used' functionality misses some cases like that.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Answer is updated. Did you mean the "Used In" tab? If so, no results. Tridion support are now on the case!

Comment: @Quirijn Answer updated. My component does not appear to be localized in any of the child publications and it's not used on a page in a child publication. SDL support have asked me to run a few queries to find out whats going on. I will update if they can resolve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the `Where Used` tool in R5.3 isn't working correctly. The component in question is used in 15000 other components. I found this by using the TOM API directly.

```
var componentID = "tcm:4-65020";
TDS.TDSE tdse = new TDS.TDSE();
var component = (TDS.Component)tdse.GetObject(componentID, TDSDefines.EnumOpenMode.OpenModeView);
var whereUsedString = component .Info.GetListUsingItems();
```

Now comes the task of deleting all these links...