# Setting Published State of an item in SDL Tridion

Tags: tridion, tridion-2011

Using SDL Tridion 2011 SP1.

Is there a way in TOM .NET so that published status of an item in SDL Tridion can be set to Published/Unpublished without actually publishing/unpublishing the item?

I remember having such a property in TOM API.

Comment: Thanks for your question, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). 
Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Comment: Yes, Bart! Did the same sometime back!

Answer (score 2):

Please specify your version of SDL Tridion including Service Pack and any Hotfix Roll ups.

Some of the TOM.NET versions are read only. Unless you are doing this in a template or event system, you will probably need to do this using the Core Service as use of TOM.NET is not supported in other code. Although I am not convinced this is currently possible using the Core Service either.

Also take a look at this post which users the old Interops: [How to set IsPublishedTo status on a Tridion Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11327484/how-to-set-ispublishedto-status-on-a-tridion-component)

Answer (score 2):

The publish state of an item is a read-only property that only the Publisher process can change. So, no you can't change its status via TOM.NET or CoreService.

For now you can still use the TOM/TDSE to change it, just like before. I believe there was an Enhancement Request done to allow this with CoreService, I'll check the status.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change because it's read only property. there is other way around is to update the "Publish state" table into Tridion CM database. there is status column that is identify as value 0 and 1. 1 means published and 0 means unpublished.
I recommended you create SDL ticket and ask for query to update the state column into Publish State table for page and component.